# g_array_free vs g_array_unref. Which one to use?

Tags: glib

What is difference between `g_array_free` and `g_array_unref`? When should I use `g_array_free`? And when should I use `g_array_unref`?

Answer (score 0):

If the reference counter of `GArray` is `1` then there is no difference (assuming you pass `TRUE` to the `free_segment` parameter of `g_array_free`). The result of `g_array_unref` and the result of `g_array_free` is the same.

But if the reference counter is greater than `1` then there is difference. Both functions decrease the reference counter by `1`. But `g_array_free` also sets the array size to `0` freeing all its elements. Other references to the array are still valid (but I'm not sure that using the array itself is valid). The array is completely freed only when its reference count is reduced to `0` (either by `g_array_unref` or by `g_array_free`).

`g_array_free` also has an extra parameter `free_segment`. If it is `TRUE` then the array elements are freed after the call. If it is `FALSE` then the elements are returned as raw *C* array (`T*` or `T[]`) in the result of the function. This is, in fact, detaching data from the array.

`g_array_unref` is thread safe and `g_array_free` is not. It is because `g_array_unref` atomically decreases the reference count, and if it is not `0` the function does nothing. `g_array_free` also atomically decreases the reference count. But if it is not `0` it still operates on the array - sets its size to `0`. Changing the array size is not atomic, and no locking is used, therefore it is not thread safe.

Actually `GArray` code is quite simple, you can learn [it](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/main/glib/garray.c) by yourself.

> When should I use g_array_free? And when should I use g_array_unref?

I would say to use `g_array_free` only if you want to get the array elements as *C* array. But actually you can use `g_array_steal` for this. So I wouldn't use `g_array_free` at all. Use `g_array_unref` instead.